# Example of a particular short exact sequence that does not split.

Tags: modules

Can somebody give me an example of a short exact sequence of $\mathbb Z$-modules that starts with $\oplus_{i=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{Q}$ and does not split?

Answer (score 1):

This seems not to be possible, see this [nlab article on injective modules](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/injective+module#BaerTheorem). We have that:

- $\mathbb{Q}$ is an injective $\mathbb{Z}$-module.
- $\mathbb{Z}$ is a Noetherian ring.
- For a Noetherian ring any direct sum of injective modules is again injective.
- If a module is injective, then every short exact sequence starting in it will split.